# Wireless (Broadcom) just stopped working after putting machine to sleep!

Tags: wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Broadcom BCM 43XX Wireless card working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-get-broadcom-bcm-43xx-wireless-card-working)

Had the wireless working on my Dell Studio 15 for months now (Ubuntu 10.04 64bit, now 10.10 64bit). But I shut the lid this morning, which put the machine to sleep; when I openend it again the wireless would no longer connect to anything :'(

I rebooted the machine, but that didn't help. I then did ifconfig eth1 {down,up}, but that didn't help, then I did iwconfig eth1 power {down,on}, but that didn't work.

So I uninstalled the wireless driver (Broadcom STA) from additional drivers (reboot in the middle), but it still won't work anymore!!

This is the trace from daemon.log, looks like it is a driver issue?

```
Nov 28 12:26:39 ulap NetworkManager[1218]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
Nov 28 12:26:39 ulap NetworkManager[1218]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> disconnected
Nov 28 12:26:45 ulap NetworkManager[1218]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
Nov 28 12:26:50 ulap wpa_supplicant[1295]: Trying to associate with MY_MAC_CODE (SSID='MY_WIRESS_SSID' freq=2417 MHz)
Nov 28 12:26:50 ulap wpa_supplicant[1295]: Association request to the driver failed
Nov 28 12:26:50 ulap NetworkManager[1218]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
Nov 28 12:26:51 ulap wpa_supplicant[1295]: Associated with MY_MAC_CODE
Nov 28 12:26:51 ulap NetworkManager[1218]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associating -> associated
Nov 28 12:27:01 ulap wpa_supplicant[1295]: Authentication with MY_MAC_CODE timed out.
Nov 28 12:27:01 ulap NetworkManager[1218]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associated -> disconnected
```

Anyone seen this, or know how I can get around this issue? It had been working fine up until now?! Even ran update-manager, but there wasn't any changes to the wireless drivers (or any related networking areas). Running the most up-to-date version of 10.10 x64.

My android phone and other devices are still working on the wireless.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. it seems a restart of the router has sorted the issue.