# Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, software-installation, broadcom

I'm having serious problems installing the Broadcom drivers for Ubuntu. It worked perfectly on my previous version, but now, it is impossible.

What are the steps to install Broadcom wireless drivers for a BCM43xx card?

I'm a user with no advance knowledge in Linux, so I would need clear explanations on how to make, compile, etc.

---

`lspci -vnn | grep Network` showed:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b]
```

`iwconfig` showed:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

NOTE: Answer below is updated every time new information is added and confirmed working.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx - there you can see that Broadcom STA driver should work with BCM4313 (:BCM4311, BCM4312, BCM4313, BCM4321, BCM4322, BCM43224, BCM43225 ) Which Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: 10.10, by the way, i tried those steps before and the card installed fine, but with the low speed problem

Comment: There's a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/732038) concerning that Broadcom chip in Natty that similar to what you're experiencing. I'm not sure if this has been resolved.

Comment: You can try to use Broadcoms hybrid driver with patch. hope [this article from mindwerks](http://www.mindwerks.net/2011/06/wireless-bcm4312-3-0-kernel/) can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: The point of Ask Ubuntu is to collect answers, not links to answers. I will only manually award the bounty to a question that provides a step-by-step solution to make the BCM4313 work (if that works for similar chipsets too, that's fine and should be noted). Also, please make sure that you tested the answer yourself and are not just copying-&-pasting something from the net. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem as well. I don't know how to solve it, but a workaround is to simply startup Ubuntu with an old kernel version. In the GNU Grub menu, select 'Previous linux versions' (or something that sounds similar to this) and then select an older kernel version. Ubuntu should startup as normal afterwards, and your wireless should work with that old version.

Comment: I had the same problem. There's a solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967515&highlight=jockey but it may not work "if your pci.id is not 14e4:4358". Mine is 14e4:4357 but still worked for me.

Comment: Have you seen [Ubuntu community wiki ?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) Here is a good [Troubleshooting procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) for Broadcom wireless cards. Thanks

Comment: I have same problem on my D630 laptop, I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 13.10 and have no wireless.
`lspci -vnn|grep Network` showed:
`0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Bcm4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)`
and `iwconfig` showed:
`eth0     no wireless extensions.

lo      no wireless extensions.`

Comment: for anyone wondering how `grep Network` (from `lspci -vnn | grep Network`) could output a line *without* the word `Network`, here is how the actual output looks like: `03:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b]`

Comment: in my case **lspci -vnn | grep Network** command showing nothing. Any suggestion..if I'm missing anything. I'm on updated 15.10 version.

Comment: With Ubuntu 16.04, and the BCM4312 chip, System Settings->Software and Updates->Additional Drivers and select the proprietary driver for it.

Answer (score 464):

## 0. Introduction and Background

This answer is based on an extensive research done by various Ubuntu users that worked together in almost all issues related to Broadcom. Special thanks to [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555) who helped in the Ubuntu forums and on this site with many questions related to Wireless devices and to others who have contributed through E-Mail, chats, IRC and more in testing various drivers with several of the most popular Broadcom Wireless cards (Huge Thanks to Chili555 really. This guy knows his stuff).

In total we wanted to offer an answer that could be easy to follow and covered most Broadcom Cards / Drivers. After you follow this guide, you will **NEED** to test your wireless connection for at least 2 hours (I actually recommend 8 hours) with another device in either Ad-Hoc Mode, Infrastructure Mode or Both. Common problems that will be solved (Apart from drivers not installing) are:

- Connections timeout after several minutes or hours
- Stops searching for other devices (Does not see any other device)
- Keeps asking for password even on cases where AP does not have any
- Stops any receiving/transmitting traffic (Needs reboot to temporarily fix)
- Crashes system with dmesg errors in log (Link 1 Below)
- System freezes completely (You can only press Reboot/Power button) (Link 1 Below)
- Creates huge log reports trying to correctly configure or connect
- Fails when installed via **Additional Drivers** / **Additional Hardware** (Link 3 Below)
- Connects and disconnects continuously every X amount of seconds
- Appears connected on Network Manager but does not receive Internet
- Tries to connect many times without correctly finishing connection
- Takes too long to connect
- After upgrading from a previous version (eg: 12.04 to 12.10) it stops working
- Wireless card does not turn on, enable or disable (Link 2 Below)
- Wireless card blocked by hardware
- More problems found in Launchpad, Ubuntu Forum and Askubuntu

Link 1 -  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1060268
Link 2 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/732677
Link 3 - Gives an error similar to "Sorry, installation of this driver failed."

So with that in mind, the following is what we have right now which is simplified in just 3 steps:

## 1. Knowing what Broadcom Wireless Card you have

There are dozens of Broadcom wireless cards and more seem to appear every day. The key to finding the correct driver for any network card is what is known as the **PCI ID** (PCI.ID). To find out which PCI.ID you have, we proceed to opening the terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (It should open a window with a blank background) and inside this terminal we run the following command:

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

You will get something like the following if you have a Broadcom Wireless Adapter (The ID 14e4 used in the example above in most cases is a Broadcom Wireless Card):

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4320] (rev 03)
```

The PCI.ID in this example is **14e4:4320** as seen inside the Brackets [...]. In some cases you will also need the revision version (if it appears) for some special cases. In this case, the revision version is **rev 03** as shown inside the Parentheses (...) at the end. So what you will need after this search is:

```
[14e4:4320] (rev 03)
```

With this new information you can look in the table below and select the appropriate method to install your driver. For example, In this case, since you have the **14e4:4320 rev 03**, if we go down the list to the one that shows the exact same PCI.ID you will see that in the columns for Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 it shows the `firmware-b43-installer` package driver. This means that you will only have to install this particular package since it appears in all Ubuntu version columns.

**NOTE** - Before proceeding, if you have previously installed any drivers, have blacklisted or uncommented any driver files or configuration files or have done any changes whatsoever to the system to make the drivers work in previous attempts, you will need to undo them in order to follow this guide. We assume you are doing this from scratch and have not changed any configuration files, modules or drivers in the system in any way (apart from updating the system). This includes any installations using apt-get, aptitude, synaptic, dpkg, software center or manual compilation and installation of the packages. The system has to start from scratch in order for this to work and to avoid any conflicts that may appear if earlier work was done.

For example, if you have previously installed the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package, you will need to remove it by using the purge method:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

## 2. Preparing the System

If you have just installed Ubuntu, you will need to build an index of available packages before we can install your driver if you have not done so already:

```
sudo apt update
```

I would even go so further as to update the Ubuntu list of PCI.IDs:

```
sudo update-pciids
```

Just in case the ID of a particular new Broadcom Device you are using has just appeared.

Now using the PCI.ID you found in the steps above, we then search in the list below to find the matching PCI.ID and the method to install the driver associated with it in a simple and correct way. The terminal will be used to avoid any GUI related issues. This applies with all cases, except as noted. The installation procedure is done only via terminal and also while connected to the internet with a temporary wired ethernet connection or USB modem or any means possible that can give your PC, for the time, Internet access. After you find in the list below the correct package we then proceed with the installation.

## 3. Installing the Package (online)

Assuming you used the PCI.ID **14e4:4320 rev 03** as found in your search above, and then looked at the table below and found that the correct package to install is the `firmware-b43-installer` (Specific to Broadcom) and the `linux-firmware` (Carries over Broadcom related drivers along with other types of drivers), we then proceed to simply install this package in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer

sudo apt install linux-firmware
```

and then reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

The format to install is pretty simple, it's just:

```
sudo apt install <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

In the example above, the **PACKAGE_NAME** is `firmware-b43-installer`.

### BROADCOM WIRELESS TABLE (Updated June 14, 2023)

```
PCI.ID              20.04+ LTS                            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14e4:0576           Special Case #1
14e4:165f           UNKNOWN
14e4:1713           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4301           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4306           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4306 rev 02    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4306 rev 03    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4307           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4311           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4311 rev 01    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4312           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4313           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware              
14e4:4315           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4315 rev 01    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware
14e4:4318           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware               
14e4:4318 rev 02    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware               
14e4:4319           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware              
14e4:4320 rev 02    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware              
14e4:4320 rev 03    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware           
14e4:4321           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware  
14e4:4322 rev 01    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware
14e4:4324           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware       
14e4:4325           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4328           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware
14e4:4328 rev 03    bcmwl-kernel-source      
14e4:4329           bcmwl-kernel-source        
14e4:432a           bcmwl-kernel-source        
14e4:432b           bcmwl-kernel-source        
14e4:432c           bcmwl-kernel-source        
14e4:432d           bcmwl-kernel-source       
14e4:4331           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware          
14e4:4331 rev 02    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware          
14e4:4335           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4350           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware  
14e4:4353           Special Case #1        
14e4:4353 rev 01    Special Case #1                 
14e4:4357           Special Case #1        
14e4:4358           bcmwl-kernel-source
14e4:4359           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware       
14e4:4360           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware    
14e4:4365           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
14e4:4365 rev 01    bcmwl-kernel-source      
14e4:43a0           bcmwl-kernel-source
14e4:43a0 rev 03    Special Case #3
14e4:43a3           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware
14e4:43ae rev 02    UNKNOWN       
14e4:43ba rev 01    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware
14e4:43b1           bcmwl-kernel-source          
14e4:43b1 rev 03    bcmwl-kernel-source              
14e4:43c3 rev 04    firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware/Special Case #2                     
14e4:4727           bcmwl-kernel-source        
14e4:4727 rev 01    Special Case #1/firmware-b43-installer        
14e4:a962           firmware-b43-installer/linux-firmware      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For All cases, always install the `linux-firmware` package if it is an option on the table above for that particular Broadcom Card. This will always be up-to-date with the latest Broadcom drivers along with other binary files that could be needed depending on the driver PCIID.

**Special Case #1** - Uses `bcma` and `brcmsmac` driver combination. Required firmware is installed by default in the package `linux-firmware`.

**Special Case #2** - For the **ASUS PCE-AC88 AC3100** the steps are:

1. [Download This file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By-7Mn6Yc0iuZ3RzclhGdnJTYWs) and after extracting it, put it in /lib/firmware/brcm
   `sudo cp brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin`
2. Then `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` add **modprobe brcmfmac** and save
3. `sudo reboot`

**Special Case #3** - For the 14e4:43a0 rev 03 which is found for example on the Apple Macbook Pro 2013, you need to do the following steps:

1. Download the bcmwl-kernel-source package by executing the following: `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`
2. Create or Edit the `/etc/rc.local` file like so: `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
3. Add the following to the rc.local file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   modprobe -r b44 b43 b43leacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
   modprobe -rf wl
   modprobe -vv wl
   ```
4. Save the rc.local file and reboot. What this will do is fix an issue with the card not working after reboot.

In hardware like the Lenovo S10-2, if your wireless card gets stuck trying to connect to an SSID (keeps trying to connect), then the alternative to get it working would be to install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package (Remove any other installed packages related to it). Read the Debugging section below for more information regarding this wireless device.

**IMPORTANT NOTE** - After September 2014, if you follow this answer and still you have problems installing the correct driver, please try the `firmware-b43-installer` package and the `linux-firmware` package and notify us via comments. There were some changes and some drivers will only work with this package. Remember to have a clean system before installing it:

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer

sudo apt install linux-firmware
```

In some particular cases, after installing the `firmware-b43-installer` you need to remove the b43 module, enable it again and even proceed to unblock with rfkill:

```
 sudo modprobe -r b43
 sudo modprobe b43    
 sudo rfkill unblock all
```

If you have a Broadcom card that has a different pci.id, please ask a new question. Once solved, the solution will be added to this howto.

## 4. Installing the Package (offline)

### 4.1 Installing `firmware-b43-installer`

To install `firmware-b43-installer` offline see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/730813/167850).

### 4.2 Installing `bcmwl-kernel-source`

For cases where you need to install `bcmwl-kernel-source` but you are offline, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline/626653#626653) is an excellent answer about it.
But basically follow this steps:

1. Search for the package in the [Ubuntu Package Repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)
2. Make sure you select the correct architecture (32-Bit, 64-Bit, etc..)
3. Download package and dependency packages related to it on the same folder.
4. When you have all packages needed (and their dependencies), proceed on going to the folder that has all packages and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. This will install all packages in that folder. If it gives any errors, read the error and follow the steps it mentions.

To give an example, after going to point 1 mentioned above, If you had the
Broadcom `14e4:43a0`, you would search for the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package and after selecting the corresponding Ubuntu version (In my case 16.04 or Xenial) I would land on the following page:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bcmwl-kernel-source

On this page I would select the corresponding architecture (32 or 64) but would also need to download the 3 package dependencies mentioned on that page as seen in the following image:

[image]

After downloading all packages and dependencies, you can proceed on copying all packages to a single folder and running the `dpkg` command as mentioned on step 4 above.

## NOTE

In some computers, before performing the commands, you will need to deactivate the Secure Boot Options in your BIOS. This applies for cases, for example, where the bcmwl-kernel-source is already installed but the driver does not yet work. You can do a reinstall like so, or disable Secure Boot by going to your BIOS Setup:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

## DEBUGGING

The following information is additional material to read about solving various issues related to Wireless Management and conflicts with other Network devices. Know that it some cases you need to have an updated Kernel version, since each new version of the Kernel introduces either new Network drivers, improvements over existing drivers or solves bugs regarding them.

Before reading the points mentioned below, be sure to have all repositories enabled on your Ubuntu system. To check, run on the terminal `software-properties-gtk` and make sure all options on the Ubuntu Software Tab are enabled.

- Make sure the Wireless card is not hardware disabled. For example on some laptops you need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
- To configure your wireless devices through the terminal I recommend [How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal/16588#16588)
- If your connection drops every so often some users have suggested to set IPv6 to **Ignore**. Just go to Network Manager (The network icon on the top panel). Click on it then select **Edit Settings**. Then go to the Wireless connection you are using, select it. Now go to the last Tab in there that mentions **IPv6 Settings**. In the Method field select **Ignore**.
- If your laptop does not detect your wireless card some users have mentioned that using `rfkill unblock all` will solve the problem. Others simply turned the WiFi switch on their laptops off and then on again (Physical switch available on this laptops). For more information about `rfkill` please read [rf kill unblock all DOES NOT WORK!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211035/rf-kill-unblock-all-does-not-work/211162#211162)
- If you are getting **b43-phy0 ERROR: Fatal DMA error /  b43-phy0 warning: Forced PIO** do the following:

  ```
    sudo rmmod b43     
    sudo modprobe b43 pio=0 qos=0
  ```

If it works then add it to you RC files so it is executed every time you boot. You can change PIO to 1 if you need to it.

- If you are having a **Required key not available** when installing a DKMS module (Like Nvidia, Broadcom or others) you can go to [Pilot's Answer Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules-in-ubuntu-16)
- If your wireless card see/not see the router and gets stuck in an endless "Trying to connect (Try 1/3)" loop the solution might be proper configuration of your router or wireless SSID device.

For all Wireless cards in general, it is very important to also take into consideration the network devices you are using (Routers, Switches, Wireless Channels and Wireless Bands, etc..). With this information you will be able to evaluate better what the source of the problem could be when you arrive at a dead end. An example would be the Lenovo S10-2 which uses the **14e4:4315 rev 01** PCIID. Even after installing the correct driver the user would end up in a "trying to connect" loop. It would see the wireless SSID but when trying to connect to it, it would enter an reconnecting loop.

The solution was that this particular wireless device did not support 40 Mhz channels nor does it support 802.11N. The router in that case was actually broadcasting with a forced 40 Mhz and on WiFi-N only. When the router was set to Auto mode and 20/40 Mhz Channel, the wireless card worked correctly. This is a case scenario that also repeats in other cases, so a proper evaluation of the network equipment would help a lot.

For cases where you get repeated:

**ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address...**

when doing a `dmesg` and your wireless connection drops often (Several times an hour or a day), the issue here might be that you are inside a wireless signal that is used as a Wireless Bridge (2 Routers sharing the same SSID and connection). This can happen with modern Routers that have the ability to extend the wireless connection by offering the same SSID. your wireless connection might drop because you might be between both routers and the signal strength between both is almost the same.

If your connection drops very often, it means you are almost in the middle of both router devices. To lower or eliminate the dropping rate of your wireless device, try to position yourself where your wireless card can see only one router or at least one of the routers has a higher signal strength than the other one.

There are also some techniques to force the wireless device to only connect to a specific router by setting the BSSID to the MAC Address of the router you wish to connect to. This will force your wireless device to ONLY connect to it.

[image]

**Secure Boot Issues**

On some specific scenarios, installing the drivers, be it in offline mode through various DEB packages or through apt-get with internet access, will not work if Secure Boot is not disabled.

This is because the access needed is denied by Secure Boot so the drivers will look like they are installed correctly when in fact the did not. So for VERY specific cases, you will need to temporarily disable Secure Boot in order for the drivers to work.

**Linux Firmware Update**

On other cases looking for and installing the [latest Linux Firmware](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-firmware) would solve the issue. Either solving minor problems that were happening with a working card or making the card work for the first time.

**Suspend / Hibernation Problems**

The user @oligotren has mentioned a nice tip here

Each time my 4350 card resumed operation it segfaulted and so wifi failed. Simply instructing the pm-* commands to unload and load the driver fixed all issues! For me, the fix was :

`echo 'SUSPEND_MODULES="brcmfmac"' | sudo tee -a /etc/pm/config.d/config`

Lastly do remember that on some laptops pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> Fixes the issue because the Wireless Card might be disabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot this work for me.


        'sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source'

Comment: `bcmwl-kernel-source` works for me with `14e4:4360` on debian jessie.

Comment: @TristanT - Awesome work!. Updated List. Thank you.

Comment: Despite following the wiki (and your instructions) to the letter, the b43 module still doesn't exist for some reason. `$ sudo modprobe b43
modprobe: FATAL: Module b43 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-79-generic` It seems like such a simple issue, but I am completely stumped here. Sorry if this should be it's own question...

Comment: Hi @TGP1994, yes please create a new question for this, since I just tested on 16.04 and it's working. Also on your question put the wireless card you are using and any additional information that you can to help anybody that would like to respond.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Alright, thank you and sorry for the attempted hijack. At any rate my problem ended up being that I was missing an important metapackage - linux-image-extras I believe. Turns out the driver is in that one for the specific kernel version.

Comment: Without a connection to the Internet, one cannot simply install `firmware-b43-installer_019-3_all.deb` because it will try to download [this](http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2) file. I'll try to follow [this script](https://github.com/mbuesch/b43-tools/blob/master/fwcutter/debian/firmware-b43-installer.postinst) by hand... Is there any other solution?

Comment: OK, I had to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/730813/116218). I'm updating the answer above.

Comment: @Atcold Excellent work my friend.

Comment: Has anyone else come across an issue where the adapter works fine for most connections and you just can't share it?

Comment: Do you folks know where to get the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package for fedora?

Comment: Sorry but none of these steps work for Dell XPS 13 + Ubuntu 16.x or 17.x or 18.x. There is a catch 22 in these instructions: they all assume that you have network connectivity when your wifi is off line, wich means that you are not on line. Very odd since the XPS came with ubuntu...

Comment: @SLS The Ubuntu version of XPS 9350 came with an Intel chipset instead of the Broadcom one (at least for some time). That might be way these instructions don't work out for you ...

Comment: @LuisAlvarado One solution which is not detailed here deals with suspend/hibernation problems. Each time my 4350 card resumed operation it segfaulted and so wifi failed. Simply instructing the `pm-*` commands to unload and load the driver fixed all issues! For me, the fix was : ` echo 'SUSPEND_MODULES="brcmfmac"' | sudo tee -a /etc/pm/config.d/config`

Comment: Also helpful: https://joshschertz.com/2017/08/06/Wireless-Issues-with-Ubuntu-on-the-Dell-XPS-13/

Comment: In my case installing `firmware-b43-installer` worked for `14e4:4727 rev 01 `
My PCI.ID is `09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)`

Comment: @Niroshan Thank you, what Ubuntu version did you use?

Comment: Its Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. I still have to disconnect and reconnect every time I start the machine, but it's nothing compared to no connection at all.

Comment: By chance are you able to test with 18.04

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with Broadcom BCM43602 on Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install. I tried everything from this tutorial but no success. `bcmwl-kernel-source` simply leaves my wifi adapter undetected and `firmware-b43-installer` makes adapter see the wireless networks but it cannot connect to any one of them. When I booted from liveusb before I installed 18.04 there were similar issues with wifi - it was working only in 2 in 3 attempts and I had to reboot again for it to connect. After I installed 18.04 wifi worked for 6 hours, then I suspended my PC and then no wifi and no hope yet :(

Comment: Sounds like an power related issue.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. I needed firmware-b43-installer but the Ubuntu installer had chosen bcmwl-kernel-source for me. I wonder why the installer chose the wrong one if this table was readily available. I mean, if I could look it up in the table, the installer could do that too...

Comment: I have the problem with the adapter... my case is 14e4:4727 rev 01... Since a recent update I cannot see the wifi networks and connect. Ethernet is ok. Currently I have broadcom STA installed. In windows the proper driver is WLAN DW1501... How do I solve??

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Working perfectly on ElementaryOS 5.1 on my Old MacBook Pro (mid 2010). Gave this old beast a new live. Thank you again!

Comment: I had quite a lot of pain with BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359], which says in the above list I should use `bcmwl-kernel-source`, but it is very laggy, dropping network all the time. Installing `firmware-b43-installer` solved the problem and wifi works as charm.

Comment: I still have some complications with my 4366c Rev 04, but this answer has helped for years, it's awesome to see it still being maintained. Note - this should be accurate now, but if you are running 20.04 focal, and have the latest linux-firmware, the 4366c.bin is included, so the download of special case #2 should not be necessary

Comment: This are great news @noybman. Thank you for that information.

Comment: Here's the line: 14e4:43c3 rev 04

Comment: Excellent guide!
my pci.id did not show up in the list - BCM43142 running on Ubuntu 14.04 (4.4.0-148-generic). Following these steps got me 90% there. Last thing I had to do was disable secure boot, reboot and voila, everything was working https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS (turning off secure boot)

Comment: Hi @IgDV what would be the PCI.ID for your card. Can you please run the command above to see which one it is.

Comment: After hours debugging this my card was hardware disabled : Dell insipron. Just press fn + F2 solved the problem!  :D
https://bippermedia.com/how-to-turn-on-enable-wireless-for-dell-inspiron/

Comment: I have the `14e4:43a3` card. Does anyone know what I should do? `firmware-b43-installer` didn't work for me

Comment: For those of you who need to install the bcmwl-kernel-source package in 20.10, here is a list of all the packages I had to install: bcmwl-kernel-source binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp_10.2.0-1ubuntu1 dkms_2.8.3-4 dpkg-dev gcc-10 gcc libasan6 libatomic1 libbinutils libc6-dev libc-dev-bin libcrypt-dev libctf0 libctf-nobfd0 libgcc-10-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libnsl-dev libtirpc-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-libc-dev make rpcsvc-proto

Comment: What am I supposed to do about ? 4322 rev 1 ??? 
 Neither of these drivers appear to work.  04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4322 802.11bgn Wireless Network Controller [14e4:4322] (rev 01)

Comment: @Daniel Can you post here the full name of your network card. Thank you for the PCIID.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado i opened a question on askubuntu.com at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438226/broadcom-4322-rev-01-unable-to-find-suitable-driver i was more thorough there.

Comment: ```sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 txpower 10dBm``` this was required as the last step

Comment: I had this problem after installing 22.04.1 LTS on a MacBookPro10,2 with a 4331 which had working WiFi during the install. The offline, manual install process in the linked topic helped me.

Comment: The table is for 20.04. What about Ubuntu 22? I have a mid2011 11inch macbook air (14e4:4353 rev 01). Ubuntu 20 works but 22 freezes immediatially after enabling wifi.

Comment: @palindrom The only tests I did on MacBooks are the ones found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUSqqx7jjNU but because you mentioned freezing, I would check with another driver (wl is the Special Case #3 I mention in the post if you keep on reading for the Apple case), along with testing in case of the power management, to disable it on the wifi as such:  iw dev wlan0 set power_save off (you need to install iw first, similar to ip)

Answer (score 111):

I fixed my problem with the Broadcom bcm4311 drivers.

Steps I took for fixing this problem (I stole this method from [nm_geo on ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10527475&postcount=5)):

(You may need to install `synaptic` or your favorite package manager.)

- Uninstall the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package by issuing the following command on a terminal:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
  ```
- Make sure that the `firmware-b43-installer` and the `b43-fwcutter` packages are installed (of course you will need internet by others means):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
  ```
- Type into a terminal:

  ```
  cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep 'bcm'
  ```

  (You may want to copy this) and see if the term 'blacklist bcm43xx' is there.
- If it is, type `cd /etc/modprobe.d/` and then `sudo gedit blacklist.conf`

  Put a `#` in front of the line: `blacklist bcm43xx`

  Then save the file (I was getting error messages in the terminal about not being able to save, but it actually did save properly).
- Reboot

After I did the above the wireless had to be unblocked by rfkill: 
  [How to unblock something listed in rfkill?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/rfkill-list-how-to-unblock)

Comment: I did all steps described above on my D630 laptop, but no success! after reboot, `rfkill list all` does not show my wireless device, it only shows Bluetooth device: `0: hci0: Bluetooth
              Soft blocked: no
              Hard blocked: no`
and yet no wireless access!

Comment: Followed this step by step and it worked! As Luis Alvarado's answer mentions, 14.04 does come with some drivers (at least for mine), but the speed is about half as good as if installing with this method :) So I guess thanks are in order.

Comment: `Put a # in front of the line: blacklist bcm43xx` This help my wireless. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, commenting `blacklist bcm43xx` out helped me in Ubuntu 15.10 WTF on Dell Vostro 3700 (`[14e4:4315] (rev 01)`, bad case).

Comment: Did steps, worked for `14e4:4311 rev 01` on Acer, on  `lubuntu-16.10-desktop-amd64`

Answer (score 35):

### Drivers for the 4313

Let's just enumerate the driver for Broadcom chipsets and how they work with the 4313:

- **Broadcom STA**. Suggested by additional drivers. Old. Awful. Absolute junk. Skip it. If you've already installed it, remove it.
- **b43-fwcutter**. Lots of people see "Broadcom" and jump on this but it's not compatible with the 4313 (which is newer). If you've installed it, purge it.
- **ndiswrapper**. Even more flaky than the STA driver. I managed to get it working for about 10 minutes before everything imploded.
- **brcm80211** aka **brcmsmac**. This is a (relatively) new driver that was recently added to Ubuntu (since the driver was added to the kernel). This *should* work well and (in recent version of Ubuntu, Natty and Oneiric) should "Just work". **This is the droid you're looking for. Use this driver for the 4313**.

  If you're not running Natty or Oneiric, your kernel probably won't have this driver. You need to be running at least 2.6.27 and I'd recommend 2.6.28 as the bare minimum (you can check what you're on by running `uname -r`).

  If you're behind on versions, I'd suggest the upgrade but for a quick fix, you can take a look at [the mainline kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) and try one of those. Installing kernel packages is *rarely* a risky thing because you can usually just fall back to an old one using the grub boot screen.

You know you're probably on the right driver if you run `lsmod  | grep brc` and you see `brcm80211` or `brcmsmac` in the output.

### Blacklisting your way to success

If you're not seeing that, something else has been loaded in and you need to blacklist that. If you can see what has been loaded, great, edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and start adding lines like:

```
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist bcma
blacklist ndiswrapper
```

You obviously need to be careful if you have another wireless device that might be using a conflicting driver as if you blacklist it, you'll break that one too :)

Comment: brcmsmac works, technically, but speeds and signal strength are abysmal.

Comment: Great, this helped me!

Comment: I have that one, but it seems I can't catch the modems set on a channel above 11... Here's what it shows up: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24360690/

Comment: The reason why I am saying that is that I can get connected to my modem through windows but not through ubuntu, so there must be something about the driver that doesn't allow ubuntu to connect to all kind of connection, excluding those on a channel above the 11... I had this issue befor with another modem, and I solved it switching to channel 11, but I'd like my driver to capture also modems set in different channels, just like it does in windows

Answer (score 35):

This is a common problem to Broadcom wireless chip.

Run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If the command run successfully try to switch on wireless (with the hardware key).

If it doesn't work or the command failed saying there is no such module, then you could try opening a terminal and type

```
dmesg | grep b43
```

If you see lines like:

```
[   17.453421] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw" not found
[   17.453427] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode15.fw" not found
[   17.453432] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
[   17.680077] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 478.104 (2008-07-01 00:50:23)
[   17.993040] b43-phy0: Radio hardware status changed to DISABLED
```

Then you probably are lacking the firmware for the broadcom card. Open **Software Center**, search and install the following packages,

- b43-fwcutter
- firmware-b43-lpphy-installerer

Reboot once. Now the wireless should work.

Comment: just to update in 16.04, there is no package called `firmware-b43-lpphy-installerer`, anyone use this method should install `b43-fwcutter` and `firmware-b43-installer`

Answer (score 19):

Thanks for your valuable response.

This problem was solved by the following steps:

1. I removed the Broadcom STA wireless driver from *Additional Drivers*.
2. Type `bcm` in [Ubuntu Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center),
3. Install "Installer Package for firmware for the b34 driver" (firmware-b43-installer)

Now it's working wirelessly. You don't need to follow the above steps. Install the "B43 driver" for wireless.

Comment: Worked for me by installing along with `bcmwl-kernel-source`

Answer (score 16):

I always recommend removing and reinstalling the broadcom drivers using your terminal

In a terminal type the following command

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This will then rebuild your driver.

Let us know how you get on

You can either restart your pc or if this is a pain type the following commands in the terminal which will 'switch on' your wireless

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
```

then

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work for me. I see "wireless is disabled" in the right corner on the top of display :( however I had marked "Enable wireless"

Comment: Now after running a command sudo lshw -C network I've got the following info :                                         *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: ac:81:12:00:76:22
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: I have a 64-bit machine, but running Ubuntu 11.04. 32-bit version. Could it be a reason of my issue with wireless ?

Comment: great, worked for me on Mint 17 64 bit with BCM43142. Thanks!

Comment: Great glad this still works

Comment: Worked for me after updating to Ubuntu 15.04. Made my day!

Comment: Worked for me Ubuntu 21.04, thanks a lot

Comment: Still works in 2022, 11 years later! This answer successfully fixed Wi-Fi for a MacBookAir7,1 2015 model on Pop_OS! 22.04 (and likely Ubuntu 22.04, too). Wifi chip is Broadcom BCM4360.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - you know what  - in the end I worked out - it was cheaper to buy an alternative wifi card BUT at least the old fix still works!

Answer (score 13):

Install the `firmware-b43-installer` package. First uninstall the proprietary driver from 'additional drivers".

Then in a terminal, execute:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

just after reboot, works beautifully for me.

Comment: This solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 10):

Finally I've solved the problem myself, but I'm not sure how. I was about to compile the driver with the source from broadcom.com and instructions provided in http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt, but at this step of the instructions

`On Ubuntu, you will need headers and tools.  Try these commands:`
`# apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic`
`# apt-get build-dep linux`

build essential and headers were already installed. I just ran the `sudo apt-get build-dep linux` command and, Voilá!, after one reboot my connection started running at its normal speed.

I'm not sure of what I've done. I guess it builds kernel or driver dependencies (or both). The BCM driver needed this step and the jockey self-configuration omitted it for some reason.

Anyway, it is fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes, the Additional Drivers Utility will fail to install a Broadcom STA Wireless Driver. When that happens, first check if your card is indeed supported by the STA driver, and to do that, open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t) and run

```
lspci -nn | grep -i BCM
```

The output will include the wireless card model, make sure it is among the models listed below.

Broadcom wireless cards supported by the STA driver:

> BCM4311, BCM4312, BCM4313, BCM4321, BCM4322, BCM43224, BCM43225, BCM43227, BCM43228, BCM43142

If the card is supported, try installing the driver manually. Open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t), and run

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

You may need to reboot at this point.

Answer (score 7):

As I've found out, to systemize this a little, there are four driver families available:

1. open-source b43 from the the [b43m project][1] that is available in [Linux kernel][2],
2. open-source brcmsmac/brcmfmac, also availalble in [kernel][3]
3. Windows libs via [ndiswrapper][4], and
4. [Broadcom][5]'s own linux [libs (STA)][6]

These links also provide reference to the drivers and lists with chipsets supported.

To be clear with referencing the different IDs, make sure to consult the STA link above prior to reading on, and comprare to yours via:

```
lspci -nn | grep Network | grep "\[....:....\]"
```

Here's an example for 4313 (from link #6):

```
BRCM Product Name   |   PCI Vendor ID | PCI Product ID  |  Dell Device ID

4313 2.4 Ghz      |  0x14e4 | 0x4727 |      Dell 1501
```

Other than the driver, you also need the firmware, *firmware-b43-installer*.

**The description below has been applied to the STA driver but has been written before this.**

Although Ubuntu is meant to be versatile, beautiful, and easy to use for everyone, packages still are prone to dependency faults. Look, installing drivers and other system stuff, it's reasonable to get as verbose a feedback as possible, i.e., do this manually or semi-manually (apt-get), avoid those GUI installers.

I've been experiencing the same issues with my 4313. Let me offer a blunt and partly non-analytical solution:

1. Remove everything of STA that you have

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
   ```
2. Install that again manually:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
   ```
3. Read the output. I've been having a nice double-liner:

   > Building for architecture x86_64
   >   Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
   >   kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

In such case, which I assume happens quite often, since (1) The inherent dependency isn't resolved and (2) There's a break in the wl interface upon upgrades (which may involve a kernel update), in such case, you should simply do the following two steps and I assume you don't need to reinstall the WiFi driver sources:

4. Check you current kernel version as follows <strike>(third entry)</strike>:

   ```
   uname -r
   ```
5. Install the **appropriate** linux-headers, which in my case is:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-**generic**
   ```

After this command you should see (as this has been deferred upon incapacity to compile during the installation procedure of the STA WiFi driver source files):

```
Setting up linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic (3.5.0-17.28) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.5.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
 * Running DKMS auto installation service for kernel 3.5.0-17-generic                                                                                                                    
 *  bcmwl (5.100.82.112+bdcom)...                                                                                                                                                        bcmwl (5.100.82.112+bdcom): Installing module...
```

I'm not sure whether the guys responsible for packages would get to see this. Still, having used Gentoo for years, I've got used to its verbosity and which may seem unnecessary coloring and formatting of output. You guys should add formatting and colors to your apt-get routine, it's so much easier, especially for novice users, to understand what may have gone wrong. And add the headers dependency, you could remove them afterwards--and surely **you'd have to rebuild the module upon kernel change**.

I hope this helps, and I'm cautious of generalizing the above path to resolve the mass issue. Just give it a try, if it works, awesome, if it doesn't there are so many more solutions offered which are notably more analytical and proficient.

I've also stumbled upon these answers (with a check

```
lspci -nn | grep Network
```

For `pci.id 14er:4727`--which holds in my case):
[Wireless does not work anymore after software update with Ubuntu 12.10 on a Dell Latitude E6230](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214156)
and [How do I get an Acer Npilfy 802.11 (BCM43225) wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213550) who refers to the former.

And I've also missed the fact that Ubuntu offers a link in the packages to the currently installed and running kernel and headers version in order to avoid defining the kernel version.

Comment: here's more info: http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/install-broadcom-sta-b43-wireless-driver-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10-11-04/, http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-broadcom-sta-wireless-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/, http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-broadcom-b43-legacy-wireless-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/

Comment: and here are two bug reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/476038, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1079201

Comment: and see this: http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/108266

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post more than only 2 links here yet per post.   [1]: http://bcm43xx.berlios.de/?go=devices
[2]: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43
[3]: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211
[4]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NdisWrapper
[5]: http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt
[6]: http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:

1. Install `firmware-b43-installer` (+ b43fwcutter automatically added in Synaptic)
2. Uninstall the `bcm-kernel-source` package using Synaptic
3. Remove the original Wireless STA driver from Additional Drivers
4. Reboot

Step #3 was a key step for me. If you don't remove original Wireless STA driver, you'll run into problems.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with my Acer TravelMate 8172 and its Broadcom 4357 controller on Ubuntu 12.04.  I had tried several solutions posted on the web for other Broadcom devices but they didn't work.  andybleaden's solution above worked for me.

Following Andy's instructions, first I removed and reinstalled the Broadcom drivers with:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After that, I executed

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
sudo modprobe wl
```

to enable the wireless card.

Unfortunately, the wireless card is off whenever I reboot, so I created a script with the above two modprobe commands to execute whenever I reboot.  This will have to do until Ubuntu 12.04 is updated with a fix.

Comment: With Ubuntu 16.04 on an Acer Aspire V11 the command `sudo modprobe wl` throws the error `could not insert 'wl': Required key not available`

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me for my Broadcom bcm4313 on Asus Eee PC Seashell 1015PEM with Ubuntu 12.04:

- don't use restricted drivers
- add "blacklist bcma" to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
- `sudo modprobe brcmsmac`
- add brcmsmac to `/etc/modules`
- reboot

Answer (score 5):

I used user 'bkratz' solution on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1928241 and it worked for me.

---

Run these:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
echo "blacklist brcmsmac" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf    
echo "blacklist bcma" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

> The first makes sure that the sta driver is in place, the second and
>   third blacklist the two drivers brcmsmac and bcma which clash with the
>   correct sta driver. Copy/paste or make sure your typing is correct!

The last step is to go to 'Additional drivers' and enable the driver.

Answer (score 4):

I first thought I would edit Luis Alvarado's excellent answer (see his post on september 7th, 2011), because when I followed the steps, it appeared the package that is indicated in the table (see his post) for my PCI.ID does not actually correspond.

In fact, my PCI.ID is **14e4:4727**, which, according to the table, requires the installation of the package **`bcmwl-kernel-source`**. This package was perviously installed on my computer, but the Wifi wasn't working (no detection of any wireless network, since the upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04). I instead tried to install the **`firmware-b43-installer`** following Luis Alvarado's answer (using **`firmware-b43-installer`** is an alternative already pointed out in his post), and it worked !

So, in case it helps someone else in the same case as me, here is the necessary information :

- Output of the `lspci -nn -d 14e4:` command :

  ```
  02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
  ```
- The steps I followed :

  1. Purge the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package :

     ```
     sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
     ```
  2. Run the following commands (see Luis Alvarado's answer for details) :

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo update-pciids
     ```
  3. Install the **`firmware-b43-installer`** package and **not** the **`bcmwl-kernel-source`** package (contrary to what is advised in the table for `14e4:4727 rev 01`) :

     ```
     sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
     ```
  4. Reboot:

     ```
     sudo reboot
     ```

And now the Wifi should work !

Thanks a lot Luis Alvarado !

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your wifi is that you are using the one forced by Ubuntu, but that does not work.  Run the following commands to get the Wifi properly working:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo reboot
```

After you reboot. Your Wi-Fi should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks for that ... but I do not think that b43 has anything to do. I read that this will be of no use with BCM4313 .

Thanks for your help anyways Petronilla Escarabajo .:)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your wireless adapter is not disabled. You can check it by running:

```
rfkill list
```

To enable wireless adapters, run:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

Comment: I tried rfkill list: and I showed the following result.

0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

so what I have to do now?

Answer (score 2):

Dell Inspiron E1505, the following steps (alone), worked for me.  I had to undo the extra steps of editing the blacklist file.

- open the 'Synaptic Package Manager' and search for 'bcm'
- uninstall the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package
- make sure that the `firmware-b43-installer` and the `b43-fwcutter` packages are installed
- reboot

Answer (score 2):

In the case where either the blacklist.conf or apt-get re-install for b43 Broadcom didn't work, it may simply be because the default wireless config still hasn't been enabled properly for WPA/WPA2.

Network folder, wireless and select Options ubuntu 12.04:

- ipv6 tab - just keep the method as automatic and uncheck the 'Require IPv6 addressing...'
- ipv4 tab - method should be automatic (DHCP) and check the 'Require IPv4 addressing...'
- wireless tab - force device mac address to lock connection to the permanent mac address of the laptop

Answer (score 1):

Good news. Based on the info you've provided in the comments, you have a network card supported by the proprietary Broadcom driver.

First, make sure you've ran sudo apt-get update from the terminal. Then go to "Additional Drivers." You can find it by opening the dash (click the upper-right corner) and typing drivers.

Is the Broadcom non-free driver turned on there? If not, try to enable it and restart your system. If that doesn't work, try to reinstall the drivers (just to get online once) manually. Here are instructions for manual installation: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

You may need to rmmod old or bad drivers. Good luck, but know that it can be done! :)

Comment: Tried everything recommended, no joy in mudville!

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell inspiron 6000 BCM4318 wireless LAN Controller
I managed to solve this using synaptic package manager

Here I :
First I uninstalled bcmwl-kernel-source
Then installed firmware-b43-installer and b43-fwcutter which rebuilt the wifi drivers

I then had to restart

Answer (score 1):

BCM4311 for my DV6000 is not working with the STA driver nor with the b43 driver.
With b43 the LED always stays orange (WLAN disabled).

With [rfkill](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/rfkill.1.html) I can see:

```
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

With the STA driver I can search the network, but the connection never finishes.
The system worked fine with Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) (x86) - now I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) beta 2 (x64).

[dmesg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/en/man8/dmesg.8.html) shines some light on the error:

> s/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. > Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
>   
>   
>      [  367.927967] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode13.fw" not found 
>      [  367.927981] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode13.fw" not found 
>      [  367.927989] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver v

It seems like the firmware files are missing from the Linux drivers(?). I got the LED back to blue (WLAN is enabled) and scanning is working with:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

This was from the site http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43.

Now the WLAN network is working for me (doublecheck for the [WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004) password was required :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have solved it by adding

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

A restart later wireless worked.

(this was taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11006092&postcount=2)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday (Dell Latitude D530 w/broadcom 4311).

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

That was that until the next reboot. Now I had to find out how to re-enable it but now the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Just installing the additional drivers, it works in my Dell Vostro 3500.

I did the following steps:

1. `sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source`
2. Then re install the additional drivers given below. I activated it.

This package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver for use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-, BCM43224-, BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based hardware.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who is getting the "wireless is disabled by hardware switch -a" message under wireless (you'll see it by clicking on the icon) - and it's "hard block", that may work in any model (that is working for me in netgear "wireless USB adapter", haven't checked the others, but it may work).

First check if it hard-blocked. Run in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo rfkill list
```

If it is, first run this to unblock:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Then I shutdown my PC, disconnected it from electricity and opened its left door. I removed the cycled battery and hit the power-button 20 long and short presses to reset the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS).

Then I returned the battery and connected the PC to electricity. I turned on the PC and set the BIOS (also for things like no diskette and boot pririty) in the [Wake-on-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) category where it says something on PME to enabled.

I pressed <kbd>F10</kbd> to save settings and restarted. After all this, the system was ready--desktop and its files. I waited for a while and the Wi-Fi was responding again.

That have already worked for me four times (it may happen any time you are forcing a shutdown or disconnecting the Wi-Fi).

I hope that it would be of help to someone too (:

Answer (score 1):

I have a b43 card and have been using Ubuntu with it since 9.04, I've used the same method to get it working since. It involves some command line usage but believe me it's worth it.

To begin with,if you already have b43-fwcutter installed, you need to reinstall it, please run:

```
sudo apt-get remove b43-fwcutter
```

I assume you know the type model of your wireless card. This method does not use the Additionals Drivers way.

After you've uninstalled b43-fwcutter reboot your computer. **NB if you've no access to a wired network on your machine you will need to download the b43-fwcutter package manually from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/utils/b43-fwcutter), as well as your card's driver from [here](http://mirror2.openwrt.org/sources/).** My card is the 4311 so I download the broadcom-wl-4-150-10.5.tar.bz2.

Once you have reinstalled b43-fwcutter either by running `sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter` or by using the .deb file you'd have gotten from the quoted website.

You need to extract your firmware from the tarball. Run command;

```
tar -xvjf broadcom-wl-4-150-10.5.tar.bz2
```

You may need to change the filename to reflect what you downloaded from the driver site, or just use `tar -xvjf broadcom*`. Then run

```
cd broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5/driver
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware wl_apsta_mimo.o
```

Now reboot and everything should work fine!

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way of solving this problem. The trick is the order in which you install proprietary drivers. The Broadcom driver MUST be installed FIRST before any others.

Example I have a HP TX2-1050ED with Broadcom B43 and ATI Raedon graphics.

I enabled the ATI Raedon driver first then the Broadcom driver this lead to the errors mentioned above.

When I uninstalled the ATI driver then installed the Broadcom driver and reboot. I had wireless. Then I installed the ATI driver and now both work.

This is actually a bug in Jockey as Jockey should resolve the driver conflict for you.

So in short. Broadcom First, then other drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not having an unresolved linux-headers dependency, cf. [After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, my Broadcom STA Wireless driver is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134926/), otherwise install them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the light wouldn't come on when I switched it to the op position. A utility you can try is rfkill to get it to come on. You have to do this every time you reboot.

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `bcmwl-kernel-source`

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 from scratch on a Dell Latitude 131L with Broadcom bcm4311. The Proprietary driver Broadcom STA was installed by default and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> that was the only thing that I had to use to enable Wifi in 10.04; in 10.10 it didn't work. I found this page and tried a few things:

- removed the Proprietary driver in Hardware drivers under **System->Administration->Additional Drivers**: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` and removed the line in blacklist.conf.
- added the driver in **System->Administration->Additional drivers**
- reboot.

This did not work.

1. After this I added the line in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf again: **replaced by b43 and ssb**. Blacklist bcm43xx.
2. Removed the proprietary driver from
   system->administration->hardware
   drivers
3. After a reboot, the wifi works!

My guess is that only the steps in 1-3 are needed.

Answer (score 0):

"Installer Package for firmware for the b34 driver" installation package worked well for me on a HP Pavilion DV5000

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution. Run the following command and reboot the machine. This worked for me.

```
echo 'options acer_wmi wireless=1' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/acer_wmi.conf
```

Comment: OP owns a Lenovo machine, I'm not sure if it works. To test it without rebooting, run `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/acer_wmi/parameters/wireless`. If it works, run the command as descriebd in the answer.

Comment: I've got a message: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Had the same slow connection issue with Ubuntu 11.04 and a HP Mini 5103 laptop which comes with Broadcom 4313. After having tried many [suggestions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx), disabling the Broadcom STA Wireless Driver from Additional Drivers window fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Broadcom STA drivers worked OK for me, and I have the same Broadcom card in my Dell. The slow Internet connection I felt was during powersave mode. [Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless) are the list of Broadcom drivers available. I have been using the opensource driver since then, and I recommend it over the STA drivers.

People say it is not available for Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat), so you need to install it manually. *Ask Ubuntu* question *[Broadcom STA driver doesn't work well with BCM4313](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27537)* provides information on installing it manually OR you can may be use the [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-brcm80211&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) builds.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [HP Pavilion dv6000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Pavilion_%28computer%29#Previous_notebook_models).

I had this issue while installing Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot), and the post *[b43 - No Internet access](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access)* helped me a lot.

Specially when you don't have a wired network available on your laptop. All you need is a pendrive with Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) and two files which you can download from a computer with Internet connection (copy them to your pendrive):

1. http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources/wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o
2. http://mirror2.openwrt.org/sources/broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2

Follow the instructions on the site I mention above, and don't forget to restart your computer (I skipped step 4 - it worked after the restart).

Answer (score 0):

For people having a Dell Vostro 1320 (or similar) and experiencing a notification in the wireless menu about a turned off wireless, this is what helped me.

The **dell_laptop** module was interfering with rfkill and telling it incorrectly that the hardware switch is off. This can be fixed by blacklisting the dell_laptop module. Open the file **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf** with your favorite editor with superuser permissions, e.g. press ALT+F2 and type

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

or in a Terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

At the end of the file ad the following like (preferably with a comment):

```
# dell_laptop communicates wrong hw switch state to rfkill 
blacklist dell_laptop
```

Don't forget to save the file. After blacklisting the module this way it will not be loaded during future system startups. **Reboot** your machine. Wireless should work now.

reference: http://launchpad.net/bugs/701259

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. b43 and bcmwl didn't work for me. b43 worked but the speed was always below 10kBps.

The open source bcma driver works fine.

```
sudo rmmod wl
sudo modprobe bcma
sudo reboot
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of trial and error I finally found a solution for "Debian Wheezy (testing)" !! - I think it should work similar on other distributions too. The main problem was the driver brcm80211 (provided by package "firmware-brcm80211") - now I use the driver wl provided by the package "broadcom-sta-dkms" and everything works !

Instructions:

add

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

to

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

then do

```
apt-get update
```

afterwards do

```
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

now unload conflicting modules

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
```

please note: your existing WLAN connection will terminate doing this!

load wl module with

```
modprobe wl
```

verify your WLAN chip is working:

```
iwconfig
```

configure your WLAN interface as usual - finished! :)

(source: http://wiki.debian.org/wl)

Answer (score 0):

Special case: BCM43142 & [AR8161](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller) on Dell Vostro 3460

The Intel4000 graphic in my case needs at least kernel 3.6 (for 64-bit: [1](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.11-raring/linux-headers-3.6.11-030611-generic_3.6.11-030611.201212171335_amd64.deb),[2](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.11-raring/linux-headers-3.6.11-030611_3.6.11-030611.201212171335_all.deb),[3](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.11-raring/linux-image-3.6.11-030611-generic_3.6.11-030611.201212171335_amd64.deb),[4](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.11-raring/linux-image-extra-3.6.11-030611-generic_3.6.11-030611.201212171335_amd64.deb)). There the needed kernel headers for the Broadcom adapter are included. But the problem is that before installing the kernel, you need to install the `build-essential`, and this is differing between Ubuntu release versions and window managers. You also need to install the `dkms` if not already available, too, which is a bit tricky without an Internet connection. So here comes a hint for other noobs like me that I grabbed from [here](http://odzangba.wordpress.com/2006/10/13/how-to-build-local-apt-repositories):

- Install your ...buntu of choice ([Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) also works) on a machine where you can access the Internet out-of-the-box (for example, on USB and visit a good, old friend with some easter eggs ;)
- There you `sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms`
- Go to `/var/cache/apt/archives` (at this location apt automatically stores all your installed packages per default.) Now copy all deb's into a folder, for example, called "BUILD-ESSE" on your USB stick.
- Now you easily can copy this folder on your Vostro and install those debs via `sudo dpkg -i BUILD-ESSE/*.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem on HP Pavilion g6 with Broadcom 4313 (14e4:4727 rev 1) by removing blacklist on `bcma` and `brcmsmac`

**Instructions**

Install drivers and firmware

```
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-common linux-firmware
```

Remove blacklist by editing `/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf` (e.g. commenting lines) :

```
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
#blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
#blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb
install wl /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install wl $CMDLINE_OPTS
```

The example above may differ from your original file

**Backup** the original file

Comment: If you removed `bcmwl-kernel-source`, this `conf` file would be removed altogether, and the problem solved.

Comment: `bcmwl-kernel-source` was already purged from my system

Comment: That file `/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf` came from that package, or `broadcom-sta-dkms` that is actually almost the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Good news.  With fresh 18.04 on my laptop with a broadcom wifi ("third party wifi" checkbox not checked during install), it show "no wifi adapter found make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged and turned on"

Turns out if I reinstall and check the "install third party software for graphics and wifi" checkbox (by default it's not checked), then it installs bcmwl-kernel-source and it "just worked" for me (latitude e6230)  Installing the ubuntu-restricted-addons after the fact didn't seem enough.  FWIW :)